# How to add images to c3.js generated charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, c3.js

I was trying to add an image to a chart - a rotated bar chart for example. The purpose is to visually set a goal for the series, like a flag.

I could add the image, as a SVG element, after creating the chart:

```
var chart = c3.generate('#foo', _chartOptions));

// put goal
var svg = d3.select($('#foo svg')[0]);
var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data([0]);
imgs.enter()
.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "img/flag1.png")
.attr("x", "60")
.attr("y", "0")
.attr("width", "20")
.attr("height", "20");
```

But it doesn't work for what I want, because the 'flag' has to be linked to a specific value among the series. How can I find the position of a certain value in the axis? Is there a way to find the transformation matrix or something. Or, is there any internal function I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using the elements parent class.

```
 var stopUpper = d3.select('.upperStop'); 
    stopUpper.append('image')
      .attr("xlink:href", "ExtGWT/images/default/shared/stop_32.png")
      .attr("x",10)
      .attr("y", (US-10))
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20);
```